# Getting Rails 1.1.2 server running on Mac script/server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm a rails developer familiar with Rails 3 and 4. I'm taking on a Rails 1.1.2 project, and the first problem I'm having is getting the server running.

I'd really love some help figuring out what I'm missing setting up the environment. When I run script/server, I get:

-bash: script/server: /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545: bad interpreter: Permission denied

This is after noting that at the top of the script/server file, there's an opportunity to define the location of the ruby install with a ruby comment:

#!/Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545

At least, this is how I understand it. What should this comment point to? Does this look correct? I've installed ruby 1.9.3 using rvm and installed rails V 1.1.2 through sudo gem install rails. Everything seemed to work fine.

Is this some kind of bash permissions issue? I really don't understand what's going on. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Something that old probably needs ruby 1.8.6 or even 1.8.4 - I remember 1.8.7 broke loads of stuff when it came out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a rails project that old will require Ruby 1.8.7, so you should start with an older version of Ruby just to be sure.  Once you get it running with the older ruby version, you can try 1.9 again, but trying it with 1.8.7 should help you out a bit.  Your `shebang` should be able to do this though:

`#!/usr/bin/env ruby`

It needs the path of the ruby interpreter, which can be obtained dynamically via the above line.

Comment: Thanks heaps! Knowing that the 'shebang' needed to point to the ruby interpreter helped me find "ls -l $(which ruby)", which gave me Users/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/ruby. And the server boots! Thanks.